# Unable to print values, The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am aiming to print the value of two values for temperature at a given time. The first part of the loop calculates the different curves for different timestep values. The nested i loop creates the plot of temperature, te with varying time, t. I aiming to show the difference between the numerical solution, te, to the temperature and the "analytical", which is defined as te_ana, at different timesteps, and then to plot the differences. dt_values has been defined as an array.

```
dt_values = [0.05, 0.025, 0.01, 0.005, 0.0001]
for j in dt_values:
    t = np.arange(0,100,j)
    te = np.zeros(len(t))
    te[0] = te_init 
    dt = j
    def f(t,te):
        y = -r*(te - te_surr) # y is the derivative
        return y
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        p1=f(t[i-1], te[i-1])
        p2 =f(t[i], te[i-1]+dt*p1)
        te[i] = te[i-1] + (p1 + p2)*(dt/2) 
        te_ana = te_surr - (te_surr - te_init)*np.exp(-r*t)
        if t == 10:
            print te[i] 
            print te_ana
```

However, I am getting the error message,

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   Use a.any() or a.all()"the truth value of an array

Could somebody explain to me what this error message means?

Comment: ... have you tried googling it?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Is `f` definitely contained inside the `for` loop? Do you have a traceback?

Comment: I've tried using np.where(t=10) instead and its printing values for me, but yes I think my indentation is incorrect because it's gone into an infinite loop...

Comment: The variable t is an array and you are using it in an if with ==.   I don't know what you meant to put there.  The variable, i, perhaps?

Comment: Your code is super weird. Why do you define a function in a for loop? Why does the function take t as an argument when its using r and te_surr, but not t? could you provide a complete verifiable example that specifies at least the type of the values (such as r) that you haven't given? 
Please explain more what you thought this code should do

As mentioned: The problem is the line "if t ==10:" as you're comparing an array with one value. Iterate over it if you want to fix only this line