# Incorrect use of np.where

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

So I am trying to calculate an error by using two step sizes, one twice the size of the other. I set up two temperature arrays which are being calculated using two different step sizes. I was getting crazy values for my error when I noticed that inside my loop where I call it to print the value of temperature at time = 5 minutes, I have written it wrong. If I substitute it for any number really it prints the same value. is np.where(t=5) being used incorrectly in this case? For each different step size, there is a curve produced which has a temperature value corresponding to each time. I would like to be able to print the values of the timesteps with their corresponding errors.

```
for j in dt_values:
    t = np.arange(0,100,j) #time
    te = np.zeros(len(t)) #temperature array
    te[0] = te_init 
    te2 = np.zeros(len(t)) #second temp array
    te2[0] = te_init
    dt = j #timestep
    dt2 = 2*dt 
    def f(t,te):
        y = -r*(te - te_surr) # y is the derivative
        return y
    for i in range(1,len(t)): #eulers method for computing temperature 
        p1=f(t[i-1], te[i-1])
        p2 =f(t[i], te[i-1]+dt*p1)
        te[i] = te[i-1] + (p1 + p2)*(dt/2) 
        r1=f(t[i-1], te[i-1])
        r2 =f(t[i], te[i-1]+dt2*p1)
        te2[i] = te2[i-1] + (r1 + r2)*(dt2/2) 
    if np.where(t == 5): 
        print j
        print te[i] - te2[i]
```

Comment: Incorrect indeed. Just use `if (t == 5).any()`

Answer (score 0):

First, looping over the same temperatures which are spaced by `dt` but then doubling `dt` makes no sense. It makes more sense to compare to the analytical solution as attempted [in your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935550/unable-to-print-values-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-i?noredirect=1).

To print the value of the result at a certain temperature you may - under the condition that you know the value is actually inside the array - index the array by the condition.

E.g.

```
t = np.array([1,55,77])
x = np.array([1,2,3])
print x[t == 55]
```

In this case:

```
import numpy as np 

r = 0.024 #cooling rate per minute
te_init = 90.0
te_surr = 17

def f(te):
    return -r*(te - te_surr) # the derivative

dt_values = [0.05, 0.025, 0.01, 0.005]

for dt in dt_values:
    t = np.arange(0,100,dt) #time
    te = np.zeros(len(t)) #temperature array
    te[0] = te_init 

    for i in range(1,len(t)): #eulers method for computing temperature 
        p1=f(te[i-1])
        p2 =f(te[i-1]+dt*p1)
        te[i] = te[i-1] + (p1 + p2)*(dt/2) 
        te_ana = te_surr - (te_surr - te_init)*np.exp(-r*t)

    print dt, 
    print te[t==10] - te_ana[t==10]
```

Comment: The use of a double timestep is supposed to be an indication of the 'accuracy' of the timestep. If doubling it results in wildly different answers its necessary to use a smaller timestep.

Comment: Sure, but you cannot loop over the array with the small timestep and then double the timestep to accomplish this, because the difference would always be roughly te[i]-te[i-1], no matter what timestep you use.

Comment: should I use two entirely separate loops to compute te[i] and te2[i]?

Comment: Yes, that's what you are doing anyways. E.g. in the above example, `0.05` is double of  `0.025`.

Comment: VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 2000 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3960. This is what happens when I try to use two separate loops.

Comment: You need to index by the condition on the `t` that you used to calculate the values, not some other `t`.

Comment: I have defined t to be t = np.arange(1,100,dt), and then later in my code I call it to print te[t==5]. Are these t's different?

Comment: t is the same in each loop step. In the next loop step t is different from the t in the previous one.